# How to solve the error "your working copy appears to be locked. Run clean up to amend the situation"

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 with ank SVN. I recently ran into an issue where I am unable to check in and I am presented with the following error on trying to check in -

> "your working copy appears to be locked. Run clean up to amend the
>   situation"

I have tried the clean up, restarting as well as some suggestions I've seen on Google. One of which involved using SQL Lite to check the DB tables in the SVN folder. Nothing worked so far.

Does anyone know what can be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have TortoiseSVN installed, you can right click on the affected folder in Windows Expolorer, choose TortoiseSVN --> Cleanup.